# Can I use a link tag for an additional attribute on the properties tab?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way to call out a link alt, title, or alias tag to populate as an additional attribute on the properties tab?

Comment: What do you mean by "call out a link alt, title or alias tag"?

Comment: Hey Adam! i may not be using the correct terminology so i will try to explain more in depth. I have an additional attribute that is appending my link (a utm value) i would like to have my alt, title or alias tag from my link put in that additional attribute field. Kind of like using a %%emailaddress%%as an additional attribute. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Web Analytics Connector (WAC)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5) set up, you can automatically append the `__AdditionalEmailAttribute1` to your links. If you need to append an additional parameter to your link, you can create up to 5 [AdditionalEmailAttributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/email.htm):

> Optional field that lets you specify up to five email attributes on
>   CREATE or RETRIEVE calls. Used to capture analytics or other metadata.
>   Additional attributes are __AdditionalEmailAttribute 2,
>   __AdditionalEmailAttribute3, and so on.

You are likely using Subscriber ID in your WAC settings since Google Analytics (*you mentioned UTM tracking*) stopped accepted PII information like Email Address. So you can contact support to add an `%%emailaddr%%` and append to your URL or use one of the 5 AdditionalEmailAttributes.

Or if you need to add the email address to the alias tag for the `a href` link then you can manually add that: `<a href="somelink" alias=%%emailaddr%%>`

Comment: Thanks Jackson. We did just turn on our WAC and  __AdditionalEmailAttribute's. I was appending the utm values manually previously and had a unique content= value for each link in the email.  
I am looking to see if I can do the same thing by having the __AdditionalEmailAttribute5 dynamically pull in either the alt, title, or alias tag from my unique link and put it in that __AdditionalEmailAttribute5 field. I thought I may be able to do it with ampscript. I know this might sound a little repetitious since the text i am wanting to add is already in my link but there is a reason.

Comment: You'll need to assign a variable to either the alt, title, or alias and use it for __AdditionalEmailAttribute5. Otherwise you can use these personalization strings: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks Jackson. That is what I am looking for. I am somewhat new to ampscirpt. could you tell me what adding the variable would look like?

Comment: BTW. i did try adding the personalization string of %%linkname%% as the description states that it is the Descriptive name of a hyperlink, known as the link alias, but it did not work. Just gave me back this "utm_content=%%linkname%%"

Comment: Not entirely sure what you need to do with the alias. Maybe something like this? `%%[ set @alias = “whatever”]%% <a href=“whatever.com” alias=“%%=v(@alias)=%%>`